# Escaping curly braces in python string format

Tags: python, sql, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have SQL query which constructs the JSON in the SELECT clause. After reading the query in JSON, string format is used to substitute the values. Because of the curly braces, string format(`.format()`) is not working. I can't use `{{` to escape the curly braces, because of the way existing logic is constructed. Is there any other to escape curly braces in the query/string?

Example string : query = 'SELECT {"Success":true, "Message":"ErrorCode"}, col1, col2 FROM Table1'

Usually we don't get this JSON in query. This is an exceptional case. That's why didn't used any JSON specific way and I don't want to change the existing notebook

Comment: please show some sample input, expected output, and failling piece of code so that we can fully understand your issue.

Comment: Why are you using the JSON as a format string? It should be a parameter.

Comment: You should also parse the JSON with `json.loads()` and then use that in your following code.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is what you are trying to do

```
"SELECT '{"Success":true, "Message":"ErrorCode"}' AS json_data, col1, col2 FROM Table1"
```

If this is the case you can use something like

```
f"SELECT '{json_variable}' AS json_data, col1, col2 FROM Table1"
```

where json_variable is the variable that you have in your python code

Comment: SQL query is read from db and stored in a variable. Some times it have date parameters in where condition. In that place date from notebook is passed. That's why .format is used. I can pass the JSON as variable like you mentioned. Because I need to introduce another variable in code to do that. I don't want to change the code